# Concatenate function return value to existent value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not even sure this is feasible and/or best practice, but any insight would be helpful. Imagine this:

```
$("#element").attr("attribute", function(){
    var foo = 'bar';
    // do things
    return foo;
});
```

This does what I expect it to: the `attribute` value is replaced. 
How can I (if even possible) concatenate the return value with the existent `attribute` value?

Do I need a new selection inside the function to get the current value, in order to return the concatenated string or is there a more immediate way/syntax?

**EDIT:** As I explained in the comments, I unfortunately jumped the trigger and didn't read the [full docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function). I was trying to avoid a new jQuery selection inside the function. The most voted answer does what I want. Instead of downvoting, please flag for closing as I did because I can't close it now it has answers. TY.

Comment: Your question is answered directly in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: @Roope yup, just noticed that. I was trying to avoid a new selection inside the function and didn't read it fully. My bad.

Comment: @Joum, Why there is no accepted answer for this post ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm waiting for it to be closed. Thought that marking an answer as correct could be misleading because of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) callback function has two arguments `index` and `current-value`

```
$("#element").attr("attribute", function(index, value){
    return value + 'bar';
});
```